# How to remove entire Craft CMS folder? or rather uninstall it

Tags: uninstall

I have to reinstall it because i f'up by changing "localhost" to "mysite.dev" on the installation page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete craft, all you need to do is delete the `craft/app` folder, so you don't lose all your templates/plugins etc. That said, this won't affect your site url as `siteUrl` stored in the database.

Here are a few options:

1. You would need to go into the database under the table `craft_info` and then change `siteUrl` back to localhost or whatever you need it to be.
2. If you have only just gone through the installation page then you can just delete the database and start again.

My most preferred thing to do to avoid these sort of issues is to set the `siteUrl` within a config file and simply reference it.

For example in `craft/config/general.php` you would have:

```
return array(
 '*' => array(
   'environmentVariables' => array(
     'siteUrl' => 'localhost'
   )
 ),
 '.com' => array(
   'environmentVariables' => array(
     'siteUrl' => 'http://somedomain.com'
   )
 )
);
```

So basically here we are setting the `siteUrl` config within a wildcard config using `*` which means it gets applied to all environments.

Straight after we are then overriding the `siteUrl` config for just `.com` domains.

See [Multi environment config](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) and [Multi environment variables](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables)

The beauty of this is now when you install Craft (or change `siteUrl` in the database) you only need to put `{siteUrl}` within the input and Craft will automatically fetch the value from your config file, based on your environment.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That helps! I ended up deleting the database. Never knew the contents of db.php is still there and back again even though i deleted the whole craft folder.